# Delete section break or page break

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to delete section break or page break at current page.but thes vba code does not work.how to modfiy it?

```
 Sub Del_sectionbreakORpagebreak()
  Selection.Bookmarks("\page").Range.Select 'select current page
  With Selection.Find
   .ClearFormatting
   .Execute FindText:="^b", Format:=True 'find section break
   fnd = .Found
  End With
  If fnd = True Then
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "^b"
        .Replacement.Text = " "
        .Forward = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
    End With
  Else
   With Selection.Find
        .Text = Chr(12)
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
    End With
 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You could try something like 'selection.characters.last.previous.delete'

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete an automatic page break. For other page/section breaks:

```
Sub Demo()
With Selection.Bookmarks("\page").Range.Characters.Last
  If .Previous.Text = Chr(12) Then .Previous.Text = vbNullString
  If .Text = Chr(12) Then .Text = vbNullString
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: good code,but how to remove pagebreak,if find pagebreak,Together?

Comment: What do you mean by that? The code removes both manual page breaks and section breaks at the end of a page.

Comment: no, it can not remove  manual page breaks （^m），it can remove section break（^b ）Chr(12)

Comment: sometimes, if you add a manual page breaks , the last character is enter (^p), word will shows short page breaks.  another condition ,Maybe the last character is not enter (^p),only page breaks,word will shows long page breaks.so  the code sholud be cover this condition

Comment: See modified code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Del_sectionbreak()

Selection.Bookmarks("\page").Range.Select
  With Selection.Find
   .ClearFormatting
   .Execute FindText:="^b", Format:=True 
   fnd = .Found
  End With
  If fnd = True Then
    Selection.Delete
  Else
   With Selection.Find
        .Text = Chr(12)
        .Replacement.Text = vbNullString
        .Forward = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
    End With
 End If

End Sub
```

the code fuction is delete  sectionbreak or pagebreak  in   current page